# Generic test plugin ignores file

Tags: sonarqube

I try to use the generic test plugin. I have the unittest.xml file with an absolute path

```
<file path="/Users/emerson/dev/sonar/project/workspace/components/triage/src/assets/test/unit/tests/controllers/controller.coffee">
```

the coffee script got compiled into js and unit tests were executed with the unittest.xml as result.

When I add this to my sonar build via the `sonar.genericcoverage.unitTestReportPaths`, it does recognise the unittest.xml, but does nothing.

The log says

```
[sonar:sonar] 14:32:55.108 INFO  - imported unit test data for 0 files
[sonar:sonar] 14:32:55.109 INFO  - unit test data ignored for 1 unknown files, including:
```

and then the path to the file named in the unittest.xml

The path is valid, why does it not recognise it ? Neither the coffee script nor the compiled js are part of the sonar build, is it therefore ?

As there is no support of coffee script with sonar, my hope was to at least include the unittest results in sonar.

Can someone explain whether it is possible and what should be written into the `path` field in the unittest.xml ?¨

Thanks for any clarification

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the files need to be indexed in SonarQube in order to import test data.
You can set `sonar.import_unknown_files` to `true` with SonarQube 5.1+ to have all files indexed by SonarQube.
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code#AnalyzingSourceCode-Unrecognizedfiles

Comment: thanks for the answer.When I set the property to true and set my coffee script as path, I get `Line 2 of report test/unittest.xml refers to a file with an unknown language`.  When I use the compiled js file as path, I still get the `Imported unit test data for 0 files`