# Scan coverage data from a ruby file in Sonarqube 6.4 with Generic Test Data

Tags: java, ruby, xml, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

As described [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Generic+Test+Data) in the sonarqube generic test data, it seems like you can scan coverage data from any type of file with any extension if you have an xml that complies with the format. However, trying to use `sonar-scan` command fails with the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line 2 of report refers to a file with an unknown language: lib/app.rb
```

My `sonar-project.properties` looks like this:

```
sonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.1:9000
sonar.projectKey=some-ruby-app
sonar.projectName=some-app
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.import_unknown_files=true
sonar.sources=lib
sonar.tests=test
sonar.coverageReportPaths=coverage/generic-coverage.xml
# Encoding of the source files
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
```

My coverage/generic-coverage.xml looks like this:

```
<coverage version="1">
  <file path="lib/app.rb">
    <lineToCover lineNumber="3" covered="true" branchesToCover="2" coveredBranches="1"/>
  </file>
</coverage>
```

which is compliant with the xsd.

According to some other flows, like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768293/sonarqube-generic-coverage-sensor-fails-with-with-an-unknown-language-for-go) it seems like it's not possible if there is no plugin for sonarqube of the specified language. However, this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34613816/generic-test-plugin-ignores-file) talks about property `sonar.import_unknown_file`, but sending it in `sonar-project.properties` doesn't work and also in SonarQube 6.4, that option is not present in  `Settings > Exclusions > Files > Import unknown files to true` as the documentation states [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code#AnalyzingSourceCode-Unrecognizedfiles).

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed import unknown files (that's the default behavior now), but you can't actually *do anything* with them unless, as you found, there's a plugin to define the language and "claim" the file extension.

As listed on the [Other Plugins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Other+Plugins) page in the SonarQube docs, there is a [plugin that defines Ruby as a language](https://github.com/GoDaddy-Hosting/ruby-sonar-plugin). However, it was last touched 2 years ago & according to its README.md, last tested against 4.5.5. The current release is 6.5.